# How to change mouse click trigger area in .NET Windows application

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows

I have some experience developing .NET web applications but now I am working on a Windows application. I have trouble understanding UI components.

In particular: There is a button (image below) where only the text is clickable and would like to change it to apply to the entire row (highlighted in blue).

So far I have found that clicking on the text calls a function in a UI class, `ProbeTree.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class ProbeTree : UserControl
{
  private void StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   { etc.. }
```

and this function is called from the file `ProbeTree.g.i.cs`:

```
void System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
    switch (connectionId)
    {
    case 8:

    #line 189 "..\..\..\..\UI\Protocol\ProbeTree.xaml"
    ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(target)).PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(this.StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);

    #line default
    #line hidden
    break;
    }
}
```

It seems that in this file I should get a reference to the entire row and attach a mouse click event to it instead of the current `target` parameter. Unfortunately I am clueless here and breakpoints on this file are not triggered due to `No symbols have been loaded for this document`.

Finally this code in `ProbeTree.xaml` is also relevant:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    ... many tags here ...
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xs:VMReading}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding}"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Any Idea how I can achieve my goal?

[image: The "Name" text is clickable]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an input binding on the stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel>    
    <StackPanel.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </StackPanel.InputBindings>
</StackPanel
```

Where MyCommand is defined in your view model as System.Windows.Input.ICommand.

Comment: Thanks @C.Lucas. Can you elaborate on what code I need in the view model? I added the lines you mention and the following code in the view model: `public void MyCommand()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("at your command sir!");
        }`
(the file is `VMREading.cs` in this case). But it does not trigger

Comment: Hi nest,  Spent a few minutes on this.  The treeview elements aren't rows.  The stackpanel  and the label in it only extend to the end of the text in the label.  You can see this by setting the background of either element.  You can make them extend further by setting the width of either the Label or the Stackpanel, but you're not going to know how far to extend it to fill the treeview width.